# Infopath rules depending on the user Country

Tags: infopath, web-services, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

How can I use the "UserProfileService" web service in  InfoPath to retrieve the "Work Address" of a user?

I am trying to have some rules around the user Country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , you should be aware of there's no `work address` attribute for the user account at AD so you will not find such this property at mapped user profile properties,

[image]

Meanwhile,there's a `country / region` attribute . but Unfortunately, by default it is not mapped to User Profile properties,  to find the default mapped properties ,check the full list at [Default user profile property mappings in SharePoint Server 2013 from AD DS attribute](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147510.aspx)

So now you need first to add new map property at user Profile for country attribute then try to build your rule based on this property at InfoPath as the following  :

**Add a new mapped property**

- In central Administration > Manage Service application > select UPS Service> People>  Manage User Properties  > New Property.
- Select Type integer > Attribute CountryCode.

[image]

**Then retrieve user profile properties with Country code via InfoPath  as the following :**

- First, you should create a data connection from SOAP web Service at Data Tab

[image]

- Select Receive Data and next then add UserProfileService web service URL
  via `http://yoursitename/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx?WSDl`
- Select Get `GetUserProfileByName`
- Now you can Create a rule with country code .
- Check how to create the rule [GetUserProfileByName at infopath](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/anneste/2011/11/02/how-to-create-an-infopath-form-to-auto-populate-data-in-sharepoint-2010/)